# Chrome Extension Template (Regex Filter) needed

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anyone know about a good chrome extension template for the sake of regex filtering? I just want to edit/add regex statements to filter certain HTML elements which I don't want.

Comment: Be aware that `regex` are not completely appropriate to parse HTML. You'd rather look for XML or HTML parser.

Comment: Have you used https://regex101.com/ it's not an extension, but it's very powerful

Comment: The question is offtopic as per the S.O. rules so I'll just comment on some available solutions. If those elements may be discerned via their html attributes or structure then use uBlock/AdBlock/Stylish extensions and add your custom rules based on CSS selectors. For more complex rules use [Linx amender](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/4407-ts-linx-amender) userscript. If you decide to code the entire extension yourself, I think you might find LinkifyPlusPlus or similar scripts useful as they show how to modify the page without breaking its events and scripts.